# how to split file extention using regex

Tags: php, regex

how to split with regex from asddhj123.png.png to 123.png

I have tried with regex below, but the first extension still involved :(

```
 /[a-zA-z.]|\.(jpg|png)$/
```

i hope that will be return :

asdasd123.jpg.jpg => 123.jpg

dsds345.png.png => 345.png

Comment: which language you're using ?

Comment: The file extension of `asdasd123.jpg.jpg` is just `.jpg`. I don't understand which part of the string you are trying to match.

Comment: try this : \d+.(jpg|png)

Comment: looks like he want filename `123` and the last extension

Comment: @CodeManiac php

Comment: @RidwanMaulanaTanjung what should be result for string `abcd123.png.jpg` ? which extension you're picking one after digits or the one at the end

Comment: the last extension? read the question.. `but the first extension still involved`, it should mean the last extension right?

Comment: @RidwanMaulanaTanjung one more question will the pattern is always like `any ranodm string-digits.any no of extensions` ? or it can be `any random string may not end with digits- any no of extensions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression is likely to return the desired outputs:

```
(?i)\d+\.(?:jpe?g|png)
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZTuoWf/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/ZTuoWf/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

```js
const regex = /\d+\.(?:jpe?g|png)/gmi;
const str = `asdasd123.jpg.jpg => 123.jpg
asdasd123.jpeg.jpeg => 123.jpeg
dsds345.png.png => 345.png

`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
 if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
  regex.lastIndex++;
 }

 m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
  console.log(match);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole file name + extension use:

```
^(?i).*?\.(?:pn|jp)g
```

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/inRBcO/1/

If you do just want the digit part of the filename as well as the first extension then:

```
(?i)\d+\.(?:pn|jp)g
```

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/inRBcO/2/

If by *splitting* you want to remove the internal part then use:

```
(?i)^(.*?)\d+\.(?:pn|jp)g\.(jpg|png)$
```

and `\1.\2` as replacement.

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/inRBcO/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**:

```
\d+\.\w+
```

**Explanation**:

\d+ = one of more digit(s)

\. = one full stop

\w+ = one of more alphabet(s)

So it gets a string starting with one or more digit(s), a full stop and then all alphabet(s) until there is no alphabet.

**Demo**: https://regex101.com/r/inRBcO/1/

Answer (score 0):

You needn't to use regex, just explode the filename. [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7bff060b227ebf41cd102c235579c7c6ca35bf3d)

```
$file_name = 'asdasd123.jpg.jpg';
$arr = explode(".",$file_name);
$file_name = count($arr)==1 ? $arr[0] : $arr[0] . "." . end($arr);
echo $file_name;
```